# Bizarre characters appearing in place of site, but only on Safari 8 desktop

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding, safari

Just came up against the strangest issue... a particular post that was published on a WordPress site is appearing as per the attached image, but only on Safari 8 desktop. Safari iOS is fine, as are other browsers.

[image: As it appears in the browser...]

The DOM (in Safari Web Inspector) is appearing as follows;

[image]

Could anyone shed some light on a) what I might be looking at, and b) how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: Do you have a URL you can share?

Comment: They are not bizarre, they are just “random” characters mixed with copies of REPLACEMENT CHARACTER “�”, which indicates character-level *data error* (bytes that do not constitute a character in the encoding being applied). So this is either an encoding problem or some other data error. From the information supplied, it is impossible to analyze the problem further (except by very lucky guesses).

Comment: No URL, unfortunately; the issue was sorted by deactivating WP Total Cache on the page. It's the second incident that we've had that affected Safari only and, from what I can tell, it seems to be somewhat related to gzip.